# How to use C++ allocated array in Emscripten generated code?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, emscripten

I have a C++ code like this:

```
extern "C" {

void MyCoolFunction (int** values)
{
    int howManyValuesNeeded = 5;
    *values = new int[howManyValuesNeeded];
    for (int i = 0; i < howManyValuesNeeded; i++) {
        (*values)[i] = i;
    }
}

}
```

From C++ it can be used like this:

```
int *values = NULL;
MyCoolFunction (&values);
// do something with the values
delete[] values;
```

Of course the real code is much more complicated, but the point is that the function allocates an int array inside, and it decides what the array size will be.

I translated this code with Emscripten, but I don't know how could I access the array allocated inside the function from javascript. (I already know how to use exported functions and pointer parameters with Emscripten generated code, but I don't know how to solve this problem.)

Any ideas?

Comment: *“I don't know how could I access the array”* – But the code you are showing does exactly this.  What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to access the array from javascript after the emscripten conversion.

Comment: Please add that to your question.  It is not clear as currently written, at least to me.  Also look again at the “from C it can be used…”, there is no `delete[]` in C.

Comment: I updated the question, and replaced C to C++.

Comment: Alright, I took back my close as “unclear what you are asking” vote.

Comment: I'd be concerned about how to delete the memory allocated inside your function by something which isn't C++.

Comment: @NeilKirk, you can always use `Module._free(ptr);` to free memory on the Javascript side with Emscripten.  I do, however, agree that it's safer to make sure that the C++ side keeps responsibility for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Emscripten, memory is stored as a giant array of integers, and pointers are just indexes into that array.  Thus, you can pass pointers back and forth between C++ and Javascript just like you do integers.  (It sounds like you know how to pass values around, but if not, go [here](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript).)

Okay.  Now if you create a pointer on the C++ side (as in your code above) and pass it over to Javascript, Emscripten comes with a handful of helper functions to allow you to access that memory.  Specifically [setValue](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html#setValue) and [getValue](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html#getValue).

Thus, if you passed your values variable into JS and you wanted to access index 5, you would be able to do so with something like:

```
var value5 = getValue(values+(5*4), 'i32');
```

Where you have to add the index times the number of bytes (5*4) to the pointer, and indicate the type (in this case 32 bit ints) of the array.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what is missed from my knowledge. If someone interested, here are my all experiments with pointers: https://github.com/kovacsv/EmscriptenPointers

Comment: If changing the function signature is an option, you could use a std::vector instead of the array. Passing around std::vectors is pretty simple using [embind](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the delete from JavaSCript by wrapping it inside another exported function.

```
extern "C" { ...
    void MyCoolFunction (int** values);
    void finsih_with_result(int*);
}

void finsih_with_result(int *values) {
    delete[] values;
}
```

Alternatively you may also directly do this on JavaScript side: `Module._free(Module.HEAPU32[values_offset/4])`  (or something like that; code not tested).